# Oracle sequence vs. table with sequences

Tags: oracle, key, sequence

I have three schemas that each need a row sharing the same data in a key column.  The processes can enter via any of the 3, but the source of the key value must only be held on one.  This can easily be shared via grants.

What are the pros and cons of keeping the key value in an Oracle sequence, vs. creating a table in one of the schemas that realistically holds a sequence?

Comment: I'd just go for a sequence in one of the schemas and then grant select on that to whichever other schemas need to get values from it. Why bother reinventing the wheel here, when sequences have been used in Oracle databases for years and are thus reliable and have had all (most?) of the bugs knocked out of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One big problem with a table for sequence is concurrency problem. oracle manages the sequences so there is no problem with duplicate numbers but it is difficult to assign unique numbers with a table. 
If you want to make customized IDs you can use sequence and in a trigger change it to a customized value based on a formula for example. However, it is recommended not to use IDs as a business column. Therefore it is better to use sequence rather than using some tables for IDs.